# Adding multiple values to array

Tags: c, arrays

I needed an array to hold 4 values defined within a function `fn1`, so I created an array: `int somearray[4]`; in main() . Although I understand that values might be entered into an array individually by number: `somearray[1]=3;`, my numbers are in variables `n1, n2, n3, n4`.

Is there a method to accomplish this?

I have considered the possibility of creating an array within the function, then transferring individual values into `somearray[]`.

I'm evidently quite new to C, and the thought of returning the array also came to mind. I'm quite sure it's not right, but it would help to have some confirmation anyway.

Thanks in advance.

To Makoto:

```
main(){
int sumarray[4];
int n1,n2,n3,n4;

int fn1(){
n1=1;
n2=23;
n3=29;
n4=14;

sumarray[]={n1,n2,n3,n4}

return 0;
}

return 0;
}
```

well.. at least that's what I was attempting to do anyway

Comment: Can you show some of your code?  It's a bit unclear what your intention is.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
char somearray[] = {n1, n2, n3, n4};
```

If you write an auxiliary function, allocate the array on the stack (i.e., put the array in a local variable), then you can't return it.  This is because it's on the stack, and will basically get overwritten in the future.  For example, you *wouldn't* say:

```
int *f() { 
    unsigned a[] = {n1, n2, n3, n4};
}
```

Instead, you use `malloc`, which allocates memory on the *heap*.  So, by contrast, you *can* say,

```
int *f() {
    unsigned *a = malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
    ...
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay the mistake was trying to define the array within the function when i could have defined the array outside after fn1 was run. Thanks guys.